# Change values in equation with slider

Tags: manipulate, expression-manipulation

I want to make an equation where the values adjust to my slider which I inserted with manipulate.

Well, I tried, but when I use the slider the equation starts to fall apart.
[image: quadratic equation in mathematica]

Actually this should happen

[image: quadratic equation steps]

Is it possible to make an quadratic equation in mathematica where the variables and their results adjust themselves to a slider which has been inserted with manipulate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Row` and `ToString`:

```
Manipulate[
  Row[{"f(", a, ") = ", a^2, " = ", ToString[a]^2}],
  {a, 0, 10, 1}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The problem is that you are effectively multiplying some strings and some other expressions together. Mathematica tries to order expressions in a canonical order. You could try wrapping a list of the elements in `Row` or you could convert the non-String items to strings using `ToString` and then use `StringJoin` (shorthand `<>`) to put them together.

---

Another approach, probably better:

```
Manipulate[
 TraditionalForm[ f[a] == a^2 == Superscript[a, 2] ],
 {a, 1, 10, 1}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that since `f` is a symbol here and not a string, it is evaluated and if it has a value, e.g. `f=3` than this leads to something like $3(1)=1=1^2$. You can prevent this by using `"f"[a]` instead, or to retain the `()` brackets and italic formatting of TraditionalForm you could use a baroque construct like this:

```
f[_] = "Fail!"; (* troublesome example definition *)

Manipulate[
 With[{a = a},
  TraditionalForm[HoldForm[f[a]] == a^2 == Superscript[a, 2]]
 ],
 {a, 1, 10, 1}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hope you don’t mind the edit. I realise my draft wasn't different enough

Comment: @Verbeia much appreciated; my answer was incomplete but I'm getting sleepy.  Time to quit I think.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard How come `Manipulate[
 StringJoin["f(", a, ") = ", a^2, " = ", ToString[a]^2], {a, 1, 10, 
  1}]` does not work ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks you would need to convert `a`, `a^2`, and `ToString[a]^2` to strings as well.  That's why I used `Row`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you very much for the fast and complete answer with the different variations ;D

Comment: @elhombre You're welcome.  I just added another one. :-)