# Why do manipulated variables display badly when wrapped by HoldForm in a plot label?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, hold

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[
    a*x + b, {x, -10, 10},
    PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
    PlotLabel -> Row@{"Linear function", a*x + b}],
 {{a, 1}, -5, 5}, {{b, 0}, -5, 5}]
```

Works nice. But I'd like to modify the label a little, so that it shows the formula with parameters `a` and `b` literaly stated, rather then converted to their values. I've been trying to achieve that this way:

```
Manipulate[
  holdedf = a*x + b // HoldForm;
  f = holdedf // ReleaseHold; 

  Plot[
    f, {x, -10, 10},
    PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
    PlotLabel -> Row@{"Linear function", holdedf}],

  {{a, 1}, -5, 5}, {{b, 0}, -5, 5},
  TrackedSymbols :> {a, b}]
```

Yes, I know this code doesn't look very pretty... But the idea was to avoid writing the formula twice: once in the `Plot`, and once as the `PlotLabel`.

But this doesn't work as expected. The `Plot` shows nicely, but the label is distorted. It looks like that: `` Linear functionFE`a$$156 x + FE`b$$156 ``

Same results if I resing from definining `holdedf`:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[
    a*x + b, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
    PlotLabel -> Row@{"Linear function", a*x + b // HoldForm}],
  {{a, 1}, -5, 5}, {{b, 0}, -5, 5}]
```

And one final example. `Evaluate` should cancel `HoldForm`, right? So I can't understand this:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[
    a*x + b, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
    PlotLabel -> Row@{"Linear function", (Evaluate@a)*x + (Evaluate@b) // HoldForm}],
  {{a, 1}, -5, 5}, {{b, 0}, -5, 5}]
```

The `Evaluate` doesn't seem to cancel `HoldForm`; instead, the label it looks like this: `` LinearFunctionEvaluate[FE`a$$173] x + Evaluate[FE`b$$173] ``

Why does this happen? Can it be fixed, or do I have to resort to `PlotLabel->"Linear function a x + b"`? Is there any better approach to what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Related: [(11121)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11121/121), [(21873)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21873/121), [(64044)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64044/121), and possibly a duplicate: [(13916)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13916/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Analysis

Let's get `Manipulate` and `Plot` out of the picture so that we do not complicate things.  All we need to know and consider is that `Manipulate` scopes its variables in a manner similar to [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html).  Now observe:

```
Module[{a, b},
 holdedf = a*x + b // HoldForm;
 Row @ {"Linear function", holdedf}
]
```

> ```
> Linear functiona$7986 x+b$7986
> ```

The Symbols `a` and `b` have been replaced with localized versions `a$7986` and `b$7986`.  The same thing is happening within your `Manipulate`.

I explained the behavior of `Evaluate` here:

- [Manipulating slots in a pure function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46751/121)

### Work-around

I can't find an older question I was looking for so this is probably a duplication of someone's efforts and method, but here we go:

```
display[expr_] := expr /. s_Symbol /; Context[s] === "FE`" :> 
     RuleCondition @ 
        StringTrim[
          SymbolName @ Unevaluated @ s,
          "$$" ~~ DigitCharacter ..
        ];
```

This finds any Symbols in the `` FE` `` (front end) context, converts them to strings, and strips the localization renaming.  `RuleCondition` (undocumented) is used for proper replacement inside held expressions:

- [Replacement inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29317/replace-inside-held-expression/29319#29319)

Applied:

```
Manipulate[
 holdedf = a*x + b // HoldForm;
 f = holdedf // ReleaseHold;
 Plot[f, {x, -10, 10},
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
  PlotLabel -> display @ Row @ {"Linear function ", holdedf}],
 {{a, 1}, -5, 5}, {{b, 0}, -5, 5}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {a, b}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Well... Thanks for explanation! What's the trick with `Evaluate`, though? Is it because it tries to `Evaluate` `a`, and not `a$something`? Also, if vars get renamed like this, I guess there's now way to do what I want to do but to move the definitions of `f` and `holdedf` outside everything? ...which, again, produces weird errors... perhaps i'm doing something wrong again

Comment: @gaazkam Regarding `Evaluate` please read: [(46751)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46751/121).  As for a workaround I am trying to find a question that I think is related.

Comment: @gaazkam I provided a workaround.  Please let me know if you have any problem with it.

Comment: Sadly, there are some problems. Sometimes the whole Manipulate grows complex enough that it would be nice if `f` was `SetDelay`ed rather then simply `Set`ted. If we replace current definitions of `holdedf` and `f` with `holdedf[a_, b_, x_] := a*x + b // HoldForm;` and `f[a_, b_, x_] := holdedf[a, b, x] // ReleaseHold;` this sadly breaks. However, this is a problem of the whole idea of using `f` and `holdedf`; the `Manipulate` also breaks if your solution isn't used. Sorry, but... er... I'm pretty embarassed to ask you for this, but... how to fix this?

Comment: @gaazkam Would you append complete code for that example to your question?

Comment: I've updated the question, pasting the code.

Comment: @gaazkam The code in your **UPDATE:** section seems to work correctly on my machine.  What problem(s) are you experiencing with it?

Comment: Sorry for that. That code started working as soon as I restarted Mathematica. I didn't know that definitions inside Manipulate aren't local to Manipulate, so I suspect that the problems were due to the pollution made by previous evaluations of that Manipulate... I still can't make a more complicated piece of code working, but I don't yet know why. If I can somehow reduce that problem to a simpler one (like this), maybe I'll post it here. Anyway, many thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 3):

I would work with nested `With`:

```
With[{f := 1-2+a x + b}, 
 With[{stringf = ToString[HoldForm[f], TraditionalForm]},
  Manipulate[
   Plot[f, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
    PlotLabel -> "Linear function " <> stringf], {{a, 1}, -5, 
    5}, {{b, 0}, -5, 5}, TrackedSymbols :> {a, b}]]]
```

which gives (now properly held and scoped, as indicated by Mr. Wizard):
[image]

Comment: This fails to localize `a`, `x`, and `b` so it breaks if these have an external value.  There is a one-character fix; make it and earn my vote. :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: nice idea to use `:=` instead of `=` in the first argument of `With`. This is nowhere documented, or?

Comment: Nice, thanks! One question: Just out of perfectionism, is there any chance of parametrization of `stringf`? I mean, something like that: `functiontostring[fun_]:=ToString[HoldForm[fun],TraditionalForm]`? Unfortunately, this attempt fails...

Comment: @Rolf Thanks the one. +1 :-)  No, it's not documented as far as I know.  I'm pretty sure I learned it from Leonid a few years ago.  It's really very useful and I have not found any problem using it; it should be part of the documented language IMO.  I took it into consideration when writing [`listWith`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30646/121) given the frequency with which I use it.

Comment: @gaazkam You will need to add `SetAttributes[functiontostring, HoldFirst]` to keep the argument of the function from being evaluated before the definition is applied.